# Why does util-linux runuser (su) fork?

Tags: su, util-linux

Using `runuser` from util-linux (a different entry point for `su`, which only operates if starting from root), one sees a process tree that looks something like the following:

```
[root] runuser -u username sometool
  \- [username] sometool
```

What's the purpose of keeping this parent process around, rather than simply dropping privileges and `exec`ing the target?

Answer (score 3):

As you see in the manpage:

> --session-command=command
>           Same as -c , but do not create a new session (discouraged).

So the default invocation requires to create a new process, because a new session need a new PID.

Additionally the return code depends on exit status, or on the signal that killed the process. This last point also requires a process monitoring the status of the child process.

I think this is due by design. Unlike `su`, IMO, `runuser` is made to be used in scripts (so never ask for password, handle error status better, and also separate signals handling (new session) from caller.

Comment: ...so the only way to avoid a fork *also* requires going through a shell (as `-c` or `--session-command` do)? That strikes me as quite unfortunate.

Answer (score 2):

> What's the purpose of keeping this parent process around

I read through `create_watching_parent` in the `su-common.c` source code. It looks like the parent stays around so that it can do the following:

- the parent calls `cleanup_pam` after the child exits
- if the child exited because of a signal, the parent prints (to stderr) the disposition of the child similar to the way a shell would.
- if the parent receives a SIGINT, SIGQUIT, or SIGTERM signal, the parent will catch the signal and kill the child with SIGTERM and then SIGKILL, then kill itself with the same signal it received. I guess it does this so that it's straightforward for the user to terminate the command in situations where the child has put itself into a different session or pgrp.

Answer (score 0):

Complementing other answers, the command in util-linux that does not fork is [setpriv](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/setpriv.1.html):

```
# setpriv --reuid=django --regid=django --inh-caps=-all --reset-env --clear-groups ./run-server
```